# как получить значение столбца excerpt где slug = services, reviews, about из БД . Laravel

Tags: laravel

Пытался получить так

```
$excerpt = DB::table('pages')->where('slug', ['services', 'reviews', 'about' ])->value('excerpt');
```

в результате в $excerpt =  только значееие первого т.е services

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже нашел

```
$excerpt = DB::table('pages')->select('excerpt')->whereIn('slug', ['services', 'reviews'])->get();
```